# Reporting / counting error using sharded counters (GAE)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We are counting some types of requests in a GAE: for each request the servlet gets the "channel" (counter index), and the increments the counter for this channel and hour. We are using sharded counters https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters?csw=1

Once an hour a cron job runs, gets the count for each counter, stores it in a more efficient structure, and if the count is much lower than the day before, triggers an alert.

This process had run successfully for some time, but recently we had one case with a severe under-count (50% and more under-count on many channels, many of them with count of several thousands). I was able to identify via logs and reference counts that the expected amounts of requests and counter-increments ran at this hour, and the problem is an under-count (either in the get() operation summing the shards or elsewhere).

Is there any reasonable scenario, in which such a problem would occur?

Comment: Datastore requiring idempotent writes might be one cause.

Comment: Sharded counters write are idempotent, and the shards avoid collisions on increments (I have enough shards).

Comment: Is it possible that datastore contention leads to partial results for the ShardedCounter.get(), which is implemented as query? Is it reasonable that this happens for multiple ShardedCounters although normally it doesn't happen at all?

Comment: avoid eventual consistency issues by assigning yourself the ids for the sharded counters. If you manage to do that, get them by id instead of a query and you will get the desired value. you still have to deal with concurrent writes and possible shard collitions (with memcache maybe, which has atomic increments)